# ImportError: cannot import name 'Workflow' from 'clarifai.rest'

Tags: python, clarifai

I'm running a `.py` file and this error shows up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Workflow' from 'clarifai.rest' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clarifai-2.0.18-py3.10.egg/clarifai/rest/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarifai version 2.0.18 doesn't have the `Workflow` class but the newest version 2.6.2 has. Just update Clarifai with:

```
pip install -U clarifai
```

Note that [`clarifai` package is deprecated](https://github.com/clarifai/clarifai-python#deprecated) and is 3 years already without any update. It's recommended to use the [`clarifai-grpc`](https://pypi.org/project/clarifai-grpc/) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I received a new error but I'm going to try using clarifai-grpc now > FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip'

Comment: @avidlearner doesn't look like you've installed pip; I'm not sure how you've installed python on your system, but if you've used brew you can try `brew install pip`.